Closed form of $ \prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right) \right)$
Introduction:
$$ \prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{k^2} \right) = \prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(\frac{k^2-1}{k^2} \right) = \prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(\frac{(k-1)(k+1)}{k^2} \right) = \left(\frac{(n-1)!}{n!} \right)\left(\frac{\frac{(n+1)!}{2}}{n!} \right) = \left(\frac{1}{n} \right) \left(\frac{n+1}{2} \right), $$
so $\ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{k^2} \right) = \frac{1}{2}.$
Next,
$$\ \displaystyle\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right) \right) = \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n-1}\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(\frac{4k^2-1}{k^2} \right) = \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n-1}\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(\frac{(2k-1)(2k+1)}{k^2} \right).  $$
Now,
$$ \prod_{k=2}^{n}(2k-1) = \frac{(2n)!}{\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{n}(2k)} = \frac{(2n)!}{2^n\displaystyle\prod_{k=2}^{n}k} = \frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!},  $$
and
$$ \prod_{k=2}^{n}(2k+1) = \frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}\left( \frac{2n+1}{3}\right) = \frac{(2n+1)!}{2^n n!\cdot 3}.$$
Therefore,
$$\ \displaystyle\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right) \right) = \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n-1}\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(\frac{(2k-1)(2k+1)}{k^2} \right) = 4\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\right)^2 \frac{\left(\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}\right) \left(\frac{(2n+1)!}{2^n n!\cdot 3}\right) }{(n!)^2}$$
$$=\frac{4}{3}(2n+1)\left( \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2 2^{2n}} \right)^2.$$
To make progress, we use Stirling's approximation,
$$ n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n} \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^n, $$
which implies that
$$ (n!)^2 \approx 2\pi n \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^{2n} $$
and
$$ (2n)! \approx \sqrt{4\pi n} \left( \frac{2n}{e} \right)^{2n} = \sqrt{4\pi n} \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^{2n}2^{2n}. $$
Therefore,
$$\ \lim_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right) \right) = \frac{4}{3}\lim_{n\to\infty} (2n+1) \left( \frac{\sqrt{4\pi n} \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^{2n}2^{2n}}{2\pi n \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^{2n} 2^{2n}} \right)^2 = \frac{4}{3}\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2n+1}{\pi n} = \frac{8}{3\pi}.$$
This is all quite neat.
But when I try to get a closed form for $\lim_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right) \right),$ here is what I get:
$$ \prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right) \right) = \prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(\frac{\left(k-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(k+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{k^2} \right)$$
and now I do not see how to make progress. Am I missing something in terms of making progress this way? If not, is there some other way to make progress towards finding a closed form for this limit?

Is there a reason to believe there is a closed form?

Maybe not, but there was a closed form for the other two... Maybe I am missing something?

There are simple reasons for the others - it is that $1$ and $4$ are squares of integers.

Yeah but maybe there is some other method I am missing like taking logarithms?... It is not obvious that this product does not have a closed form. And besides, I am sure someone has studied this before and has a definitive answer, as it is surely one of the most natural infinite products (that we know converges) that one first investigates.

Yes, sorry, edited.

Mathematica gives : $$\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\prod _{k=2}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{2 k^2}\right)=\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{2 \sqrt{2} \Gamma \left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+n\right) \Gamma
\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+n\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\pi  \Gamma (1+n)^2}=\frac{2 \sqrt{2} \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\pi }$$

Cool! I wonder how you arrive at that!

Maybe from this: $\prod _{k=2}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{2 k^2}\right)=\exp \left(\sum _{k=2}^n \ln \left(1-\frac{1}{2 k^2}\right)\right)$ ? for general: $\prod _{k=2}^n \left(a-\frac{b}{k^2}\right)=\frac{a^n \left(1-\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}}\right)_n \left(1+\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}}\right)_n}{(a-b) (n!)^2}$

Maybe related to Wallis product?

The Weierstrass factorisation of $\sin(\pi x)$ yields
$$
\sin(\pi x)=\pi x \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)
$$
for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. This result can be found as an application of Weierstrass’ factorisation theorem or other more direct methods. Plugging in $x=\frac{\sqrt{2}}2=\frac 1 {\sqrt2}$ yields
$$
\frac{\sqrt{2}\sin(\frac\pi{\sqrt{2}})}{\pi}= \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{2n^2}\right),
$$
and if we divide both sides by the first factor $1-\frac{1}{2n^2}$ where $n=1$ we obtain
$$
\frac{2\sqrt{2}\sin(\frac\pi{\sqrt{2}})}{\pi}= \prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{2n^2}\right)
$$
which coincides with the result given by Mathematica thanks to @Mariusz.

If we make the problem more general
$$P_a=\prod_{k=2}^n  \left(1-\frac{1}{a k^2}\right)=\frac{\prod_{k=2}^n  (ak^2-1)}{{\prod_{k=2}^n  ak^2}} $$
Using Pochhammer symbol , the numerator is
$$\frac{a^n   \left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\right)_n
   \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\right)_n}   {a-1}$$ Using the gamma function, this is $$\frac{a^{n+\frac{1}{2}} \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{a}}\right) \Gamma
   \left(n-\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}+1\right) \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}+1\right)}{\pi  (a-1)}$$
The denominator is $$a^{n-1} \Gamma (n+1)^2$$
Taking logarithms, using Stirling approximation and exponentiating
$$P_a=\frac{a^{3/2} \sin \left(\frac{\pi
   }{\sqrt{a}}\right)}{\pi  (a-1)} \Bigg( 1+\frac{1}{a n}-\frac{a-1}{2 a^2 n^2}+
O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\Bigg)$$ Then, the limit.
